# Ordenação de lista encadeada

Tags: java, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Estou realizando um trabalho que preciso criar uma lista encadeada e ordená-la em ordem crescente, realizando meus testes percebi que estou perdendo a referencia para um nodo, o problema pode ser lógico mas não estou conseguindo achar meu erro.

metodo para adicionar e ordenar:

```
public void adiciona(Nodo novoNodo) {

    for (Nodo i = primeiroNodoDistancia; i != null; i = i
            .getProximoNodoDistancia()) {
        if (i.getDistancia() > novoNodo.getDistancia()) {
            novoNodo.setProximoNodoDistancia(i);
            if (i.getNodoAnteriorDistancia() != null) {
                novoNodo.setNodoAnteriorDistancia(i
                        .getNodoAnteriorDistancia());
                i.getNodoAnteriorDistancia().setProximoNodoDistancia(
                        novoNodo);
                i.setNodoAnteriorDistancia(novoNodo);
            } else {
                i.setNodoAnteriorDistancia(novoNodo);

            }
            if (i == primeiroNodoDistancia)
                primeiroNodoDistancia = novoNodo;
        }
        if (novoNodo.getDistancia() > i.getDistancia()) {
            novoNodo.setNodoAnteriorDistancia(i);
            if (i.getProximoNodoDistancia() != null) {
                novoNodo.setProximoNodoDistancia(i
                        .getProximoNodoDistancia());
                i.getProximoNodoDistancia().setNodoAnteriorDistancia(
                        novoNodo);
            }
            i.setProximoNodoDistancia(novoNodo);
        }

    }

}
```

Meu código para teste esta assim:

```
    c.adicionar(pedro, 50);
    System.out.println(c.imprimirListaDistancia());

    c.adicionar(joao, 20);
    System.out.println(c.imprimirListaDistancia());

    c.adicionar(maria, 10);
    System.out.println(c.imprimirListaDistancia());
```

Saida do Terminal:

```
 Pedro
 Joao Pedro
 Maria Pedro
```

Estou perdendo a referencia para o joao que deveria ficar no meio da lista..

Comment: Poderia postar todo o seu código, inclusive o da classe Nodo. Uma dica: Java tem uma implementacões de Lista duplamente encadeada, LinkedList é uma delas, existem outras, consulte a interface java.util.Deque

Comment: Olá Filipe não posso usar nenhuma implementação já existente do Java. não postei a classe Nodo pois ela é bem especifica para o problema como um todo, a ordenação é somente um deles..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua função tem um problema que é que seu `for` vai rodar independente de você ter encontrado a posição certa ou não, o problema acontece mais ou menos assim:

- Adicionar **pedro**, está vazio então sem problemas
- Adicionar **joao**, cai no primeiro if, faz o que é preciso ser feito e como não tem próximo para ai.
- Adicionar **maria**, cai no primeiro if, faz o que é preciso ser feito, passa para o próximo e compara **NOVAMENTE** com o *novoNodo* e começa a bagunçar toda sua lista.

Eu implementei uma forma diferente pra adicionar, segue:

```
public void adicionar(Nodo novoNodo) {
    // está vazio, só adicionar e ir embora
    if (primeiroNodoDistancia == null) {
        primeiroNodoDistancia = novoNodo;
        return;
    }

    Nodo aux = primeiroNodoDistancia;
    Nodo anterior = null;
    // Procura a posição que o novo será adicionado
    while (aux != null) {
        if (aux.getDistancia() > novoNodo.getDistancia()) {
            break;
        }
        anterior = aux;
        aux = aux.getProximoNodoDistancia();
    }

    if (anterior == null) { // inserir no começo
        primeiroNodoDistancia.setNodoAnteriorDistancia(novoNodo);
        novoNodo.setProximoNodoDistancia(primeiroNodoDistancia);
        primeiroNodoDistancia = novoNodo;
    } else { // vai inserir entre o anterior e o aux (proximo)
        anterior.setProximoNodoDistancia(novoNodo);
        novoNodo.setNodoAnteriorDistancia(anterior);
        novoNodo.setProximoNodoDistancia(aux);

        if (aux != null) { // se for nulo ele é o ultimo
            aux.setNodoAnteriorDistancia(novoNodo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @MaiconCarraro obrigado pela ajuda, modifiquei conforme minha necessidade e funcionou perfeitamente.